# Mercurial, Get history of branch since last tag - including merged in commits

Tags: mercurial, revision-history

With Mercurial, I'm trying to get the history of a branch since the last tag.
BUT I want to include all the comments that were merged in as well.

Our devs usually create a branch, do some work, possibly multiple commits, then merge the branch back in.

Using: hg log -b . -r "last(tagged())::" --template "{desc|firstline}\n"

I'll get entries like "Merge" - with no information on what commits were included in that merge.

How do I get it to include the merged commits?
We also have multiple active branches, so just including ALL commits for ALL branches won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues here that seem (after analysis) to stem from using `-b .`.  There may be more issues as well.  I will take them in some order, not necessarily the best one, perhaps even the worst one. :-)

#### Combining `-b` and `last(set)` seems unwise in general

Your `-b .` constraint means you get only commits that are on the current branch.  If your revset would otherwise include commits on another branch, those commits will be excluded.  Or, to put it another (more set-theoretic) way, using `-b .` within `hg log` is a bit like taking whatever revset specifier you have and adding:

```
(revset) & branch(.)
```

—though simply asking this question this brought up one point I was unsure about: is the limiting done *before* calculating `tagged()`, or after?  Some poking-about in `hg --debugger` tells me that it's "after", which means we get:

```
(last(tagged()) & (branch(.))
```

which means that if there are tags on, e.g., revs 1, 7, and 34, we'll select rev 34 first, then select revisions whose branch is the current branch.  Suppose that rev 7 is a member of the current branch, but rev 34 is not.  The result of the `&` is then the empty set.

That's probably not the issue here—the actual final expression is, or might as well be, `branch(.) & descendants(last(tagged()))`—but in at least some cases, it would probably be better to use:

```
last(tagged() & branch(.))
```

so that you start with the last revision that is both tagged, and on the current branch.  (If this revlist is empty it's not clear what you should do next, but that is hard to program at this level, so let's just assume the revlist has one revision in it, e.g., rev 7 in our example here.)

This is probably not what you want after all, though; see the last section below.

#### Combining `-b` and a DAG range

A DAG-range operator like `X::Y` in Mercurial simply means: *All commits/revisions that are descendants of `X`, including `X` itself, and ancestors of `Y`, including `Y` itself.*  Omitting `Y` entirely means *all descendants of `X`*.  Without a `-b` limiter, you will get *all* such commits, but with `-b .`, you once again restrict yourself to those commits that on the *current* branch.

If you merge commits within one branch, then, you will get the merge commits and their ancestors and descendants that are on this branch.  (Remember that in Mercurial, any commit is on exactly one branch, forever: this is the branch that was current when the commit itself was made.)  But if you are using branches at all in Mercurial, you are probably merging commits that are in other branches.  If you want to see *any* those commits, you cannot use `-b .` here.

#### Getting what you want

Let's go back to your first statement above:

> With Mercurial, I'm trying to get the history of a branch since the last tag. BUT I want to include all the [commits] that were merged in as well.

Let's draw a quick example or two and see which commits you might want.

Here's a horizontal graph, with newer commits toward the right.  Each commit is represented by an `o` unless it is tagged, in which case it is represented by a `*`.  There are several merges.  Commits on the first two rows are on branch B1 and commits on the third row are on branch B2.

```
    o--o---o--o---o--*--o--o--o
b1:     \    /            /
         *--o            /
             \          /
b2:           o--*--o--o--o--o
```

It's not clear to me which commits you wish to see.  The last tagged commit on `b1` is the top row `*`, but there is a tagged commit on `b2` as well (whose rev number is probably lower than the one on `b1`).  Or suppose we had a slightly different graph, so that the highest numbered tagged revision were one on `b2`:

```
    o--o---o--o---*--o--o--o--o
b1:     \    /            /
         *--o            /
             \          /
b2:           o--o--*--o--o--o
```

If we use the expression `last(tagged())` without any branch masking, we will choose the rightmost starred commit.  If we then feed that into a DAG operator (e.g., as `X` in `X::` or using `descendants()`, we get all the commits that are "after" that one.

When we start with the single starred commit on `b2`—as in the last graph—we get that commit and the remaining three commits that are on `b2`, plus the last two commits that are on `b1`.  That *may* be what you want, but perhaps you also want some commits that are on `b1` that come *before* the merge, but after (and maybe including) the final starred commit that is on `b1` itself.

Note that this is what you get with just `descendants(last(tagged())`, i.e., if you remove `-b .` from your original `hg log` command.

---

When we start with the last starred commit on `b1`, though, as in the earlier graph, we get just that commit plus the final three commits on branch `b1`.  None of the commits on branch `b2` that get merged are descendants of the starred commit we chose.  So the DAG-range approach itself is suspect, here.  Still, if eliminating tagged commits that are directly on `b1` suffices, note that we can use:

```
descendants(last(tagged() and not branch(b1)))
```

(there is no difference between `and` and `&` here, I just spelled it out because I spelled out `not`).

---

There is another possibility that I see here: perhaps you want *any* commits that are ancestors of the current branch's final commit, but stopping at:

- any tagged commit, or
- any predecessor merge for any *other* branch than the first-merged branch arrived-at by traversing ancestors.

Visualizing this last case requires a more complex branch topology, with more than two total named branches.  Since it's (a) hard and (b) not at all clear to me that this *is* what you want, I'm not going to write an expression to produce it.

Comment: Wow, a doctoral thesis!  WAY beyond my hg skills!
So, using your 2nd example diagram.
I'm specifically interested in whatever has lead up to the current state of b1.  We tag a branch each time we build an installer from it.
So I want everything that has gone into b1 since the last time b1 was tagged.
Looks like that would be the last 4 changes on b1, and the first 3 changes on b2.
Does that clarify things?

Comment: It does (clarify things). I'm not sure how best to write this in Mercurial though (I'm more familiar with doing things in Git, which really requires a lot of graph theory since the branch names in Git are nearly meaningless—so there may be a shorter way in hg). We might want to look at commits in the (tag-on-b1::end-of-b1) range and for any that are merges, look at their p2() and reach back from there to tag-on-that-branch. Coding that in shell, or a Mercurial extension in Python, is then just a Small Matter Of Programming, but maybe not that small. :-)